# when i click list button it not responding

Tags: android

```
04-05 14:58:47.224: I/System.out(264): /mnt/sdcard

04-05 14:59:21.451: D/dalvikvm(264): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5029 objects / 258800 bytes in 242ms

04-05 14:59:21.500: D/AndroidRuntime(264): Shutting down VM

04-05 14:59:21.500: W/dalvikvm(264): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264): FATAL EXCEPTION: main


04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264): java.lang.IllegalStateException:
 Could not find a method playMyRecord(View) in the activity class com.example.projectlayout.Showlist for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'

04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2059)

04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)

04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: playMyRecord
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:308)
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:985)
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2052)
04-05 14:59:21.570: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  ... 11 more
04-05 14:59:25.211: I/Process(264): Sending signal. PID: 264 SIG: 9
04-05 15:01:05.641: I/System.out(322): /mnt/sdcard
04-05 15:01:33.525: D/dalvikvm(322): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5117 objects / 262576 bytes in 196ms
04-05 15:01:33.581: D/AndroidRuntime(322): Shutting down VM
04-05 15:01:33.581: W/dalvikvm(322): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method playMyRecord(View) in the activity class com.example.projectlayout.Showlist for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2059)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: playMyRecord
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:308)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:985)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2052)
04-05 15:01:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  ... 11 more
04-05 15:01:36.671: I/Process(322): Sending signal. PID: 322 SIG: 9
04-05 15:08:43.890: D/AndroidRuntime(394): Shutting down VM
04-05 15:08:43.890: W/dalvikvm(394): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projectlayout/com.example.projectlayout.Showlist}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at com.example.projectlayout.Showlist.onCreate(Showlist.java:41)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-05 15:08:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(394):  ... 11 more
04-05 15:08:53.431: I/Process(394): Sending signal. PID: 394 SIG: 9
04-05 15:21:31.830: D/AndroidRuntime(418): Shutting down VM
04-05 15:21:31.830: W/dalvikvm(418): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projectlayout/com.example.projectlayout.Showlist}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.example.projectlayout.Showlist.onCreate(Showlist.java:41)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-05 15:21:31.850: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  ... 11 more
04-05 15:21:34.860: I/Process(418): Sending signal. PID: 418 SIG: 9
04-05 15:23:37.880: I/System.out(447): /mnt/sdcard
04-05 15:23:58.000: D/AndroidRuntime(447): Shutting down VM
04-05 15:23:58.000: W/dalvikvm(447): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projectlayout/com.example.projectlayout.Showlist}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at com.example.projectlayout.Showlist.onCreate(Showlist.java:41)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-05 15:23:58.031: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your code also please.

Comment: You apparently have a Button `button1` in your layout with `android:onClick="playMyRecord"`, but you don't have a method `public void playMyRecord(View v)` in the `Showlist` Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting click event of list button,you have to set click listener in adapters GetView method like this

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        private int mPosition;

        OnItemClickListener(int position) {
            mPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // do whatever you want to do
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not find a method playMyRecord(View) in the activity class com.example.projectlayout.Showlist for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
```

from your logcat i can figure out that you declared method of onclick in xml but has not defined that method in java file.
 so just declare that method playMyRecord(View) in your case in java file